# Proper Mapping for dynamic fields

Tags: json, mapping, elasticsearch

I have the following document structure:

```
{
  "some_field": "some_data",
  "entries": {
    {"id": "some_id", "type": "some_type", "value": "some_value"},
    {"id": "another_id", "type": "another_type", "value": {"foo": 1, "bar": "two"}
  }
}
```

So I would like to map entries based on the "type" field.
Which maping type or flag should I use?
Or maybe I need to change my doc structure?

Comment: with your current structure, which of the "type" fields would you use for your mapping? Are the two "entries" objects to be indexed as separate documents or is the whole object a single document? Maybe you could provide a description of the actual objects and their relationships.

Comment: the two entries should be indexed using the "value" field

Answer (score 1):

Could you use this one

```
{
   "some_field":"some_data",
   "entries":[{
         "id":"some_id",
         "type":"some_type",
         "value":"some_value"
      },
      {
         "id":"another_id",
         "type":"another_type",
         "value":{
            "foo":1,
            "bar":"two"
         }
      }]
}
```

Comment: why using a list will make a difference ?

Comment: It is json syntax. Unless how to understand which is object or which is array you can check your json in this site http://jsonlint.com/ and json syntax http://json.org/

Comment: The problem I see is that unless the two entries are indexed as nested documents, the original question is not answered, since you can't index as single document mapping it with two "type" fields.

Comment: Because you should use any loop for entries